# Function to generate a calculated property for use with Format-Table

Tags: powershell

Here's a simple list of two objects:

```
$ls = 
    [PSCustomObject]@{ a = 10; b = 20; c = 30; },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ a = 40; b = 50; c = 60; }
```

Display the list using `ft` with calculated properties:

```
$ls | ft `
    @{ Label = ':a:'; Expression = { $_.a } }, 
    @{ Label = ':b:'; Expression = { $_.b } }, 
    @{ Label = ':c:'; Expression = { $_.c } }
```

We get:

```
:a: :b: :c:
--- --- ---
 10  20  30
 40  50  60
```

Those calculated properties are a lot to type. So, it would be nice to have a function to create one for us.

So, something like this:

```
function create-format ($name)
{
    @{ Label = (':{0}:' -f $name); Expression = { $_.$name } }
}
```

So that we can do this:

```
$ls | ft `
    (create-format 'a'), 
    (create-format 'b'), 
    (create-format 'c')
```

Of course, that doesn't work.

It doesn't work because the scriptblock:

```
{ $_.$name }
```

doesn't end up with the `$name` evaluated.

We can see this in action. If we call:

```
create-format 'a'
```

we get:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Expression                      $_.$name
Label                          :a:
```

## Question

What's a good way to setup `create-format`?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do the trick:

```
function create-format ($name)
{
    @{ 
        Label = (':{0}:' -f $name)
        Expression = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create('$_.' + $name)
    }
}
```

## Real-world example

Here's an example of one using the above technique:

```
function create-format ($name)
{
    @{ 
        Label = $name
        Expression = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create('$_.{0}.ToString("N0")' -f $name)
        Align = 'right'
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need a scriptblock in this case, the expression can just be the property name. `@{ Label = (':{0}:' -f $name); Expression = $name }`

Comment: if a scriptblock was required then you can use `Expression = { $_.$name }.GetNewClosure()`